# Function returning false on array and integer compare?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to check if an integer value exists in an array, but the function is returning false even if the integer exists in the array.

This is code I am using. The error is 404 but it is returning false:

```
const
  cErrors: array [0 .. 3] of integer = (401, 404, 409, 411);

function isInError(const error: integer; const sArray: array of integer): Boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i in sArray do
    if sArray[i] = error then
      Result := True;
  ShowMessage(error.ToString);// it's returining false always and this showmessage is just verify the error code
end;
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
if (isInError(sPdf.LastErrorCode, cErrors)) then
  ShowMessage(sPdf.LastErrorCode.toString);
```

Comment: What values do you expect `i` to hold in your line `for i in sArray`? When you single step in the debugger through the code, what values do you see for `i` and for `sArray[i]`? Btw, default setting for range checking is off. I suggest you go to `Project - Options` and enable `Compiler settings - Range checking`

Comment: @TomBrunberg at first point i see `var i is 75395520` `sArray is 401 404 409 411` and in next the `var i is 401` then `var i is 404` and so on.

Comment: I also asked: *What values do you **expect** `i` to hold in your line `for i in sArray`?*. What is your answer to that one?

Comment: @Amo, what Tom is saying is a hint so you can figure out the mistake. A `for..in` loop iterates the array content, not its indexes. With range checking on, you would have found the error instantly.

Comment: As @LURD said, a `for..in` loop iterates the content, as you already saw 401, 402 .... IOW you can compare `i`with `error`. If you would use the conventional way, `for i := 0 to Length(array)-1 do ...` then you would use your current `if array[i] = error` ...

Comment: @TomBrunberg #@LURD Thank you for helping it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
  for i in sArray do
    if sArray[i] = error then
```

The `for .. in` already extracts values from the array.

```
  for i in sArray do
    if i = error then
```

Also turn on range checking to make sure you are not going outside of array boundaries.